# Calculations of polyline coordinates not defined in data() scope

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a problem of calculation a `"d"` attribute for `svg:poly` element. I made the model of the situation:

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/2efxadLy/1/

```
// array of points
var points = [{
    name: "a",
    coord: [22, 35]
}, {
    name: "b",
    coord: [2, 55]
}, {
    name: "c",
    coord: [42, 5]
}, {
    name: "d",
    coord: [5, 57]
}];

// array of connectors
var connectors = [
    ["a", "c"],
    ["b", "c"],
    ["d", "a"]
];

// styles
var styles = {
line: {
    "stroke": "black",
    "stroke-width": 1,
    "fill": "none"
},
board: {
    "width": 100,
    "height": 100
}};

// svg element
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr(styles.board);

// three connectors between points
var path = svg.selectAll("path").data(connectors).enter().append("svg:path").attr(styles.line);
// attempt to fill the "d" attribute of the path
path.attr("d", function (d) {// d -- the array of connector pair ["a", "c"] etc. 
    var from = d[0],// "a"
        to = d[1],// "c"
        point_from = points.filter(function (item) {// [22,35]
            return (item.name === from);
        })[0],
        point_to = points.filter(function (item) {// [42,5]
            return (item.name === to);
        })[0];
    var coords = [point_from, point_to];
    // ERROR!
    // I can not place coords in line() function
    // the line() function expects some "d3.data" type argument
    // but there is no "d3.selection" to produce this data type
    var l = d3.svg.line(/* missed content */).extrapolate("basis");
    return(l);
});
```

As result, I have 3 `path` without "d" attribute:

[image]

I know, that I can use the pattern, where I will add connectors one by one:

```
var line_function = d3.svg.line().x(function(d) {
            return (d.x);
        }).y(function(d) {
            return d.y;
        }).interpolate("basis");

connectors.forEach(function(pair){
    var from = pair[0], to = pair[1];
    var coordinate_array = [{x: ..., y; ...},{x: ..., y; ...}];
    board.data(coordinate_array).enter().append("svg:path").attr("d", line_function(coordinate_array)).attr(...);
});
```

But I looking for some "inline", native `d3` solution. And solution where I should "prepare the data" before drawing is not working in my situation. It's just a model of complex problem. Sorry!

Comment: I can't dream up a way of doing this without explicitly looping the data.  You can shift that loop into the `d3` processing but that just seems like semantics:  http://jsfiddle.net/2efxadLy/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is the line generator function `d3.svg.line()` should be inline called as `(fn)()`:

```
path.attr("d", (d3.svg.line())(/* points */));
```

As argument, mentioned as `points`, we can use the function with the dots array return like:

```
path.attr("d", (d3.svg.line())(function(){
    return([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]);
}));
```

Methods `x()` and `y()` should be used just in case of associative arrays of coordinates and can be avoided in case points defined as the pairs array:

```
[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/602fxj2e/

Finally, my example code should be corrected this way:

```
// svg element
var p = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr(styles.board).selectAll("path").data(connectors).enter().append("svg:path").attr(styles.line)
    .attr("d", function (d) {
    var from = d[0], // "a"
        to = d[1], // "c"
        point_from = points.filter(function (item) { // [22,35]
            return (item.name === from);
        })[0].coord,
        point_to = points.filter(function (item) { // [42,5]
            return (item.name === to);
        })[0].coord,
        dots = [point_from, [point_from[0] + 100, point_from[1] + 50], // just to make it looks funny
            [point_to[0] + 200, point_to[1] + 100], point_to];
    return ((d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis"))(dots));
    // simple return should be [point_from, point_to]
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2efxadLy/6/

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you're slightly misunderstanding the way `d3.svg.line()` is used. In this example:

```
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
```

`lineGenerator` is a function, which takes an array of points and returns a String that is the path description assigned to the attribute `<path d="...">`.

In all this, there is no requirement to bind to a d3 selection.

So you can create a generator for the path description you need based on your `coords` array like this:

```
// converts an array of 2 points (coords) or svg line path data
var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(point) { return point.coord[0]; })
  .y(function(point) { return point.coord[1]; })
  .interpolate("basis")
```

Later, inside `path.attr("d", function (d) { ... })`, after you've assembled `var coords = [point_from, point_to]`, simply call the line generator.

```
return lineGenerator(coords);
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2efxadLy/4/)